# script jQuery floating footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery code which i am using to float a div when I scroll down

```
  var top = jQuery('#sider').offset().top - parseFloat(jQuery('#sider').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

    // whether that's below the form
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, ad the fixed class
      jQuery('#sider').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      // otherwise remove it
      jQuery('#sider').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
```

But I have also a div which is at the bottom of body, and I want to show that div 
what changes I need to made to this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this is acceptable?

http://jsfiddle.net/Cvgdz/1/

maybe you need to change the floatDiv height of my example..